# Why is Migrations looking for Sql Server Provider?

Tags: entity-framework, postgresql, entity-framework-6, npgsql

Here is my config...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DataContext" connectionString="Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=myDatabase;User Id=postgres;Password=password;Preload Reader = true;" providerName="Npgsql" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, Npgsql.EntityFramework" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

When I run `update-database` it gives at the end of the stack trace...

> No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with
>   invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'. Make sure the provider is
>   registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config
>   file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more
>   information.

Another error I'm running into when I add to the entityFramework section..

```
 <defaultConnectionFactory type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" />
```

> Failed to set Database.DefaultConnectionFactory to an instance of the
>   'Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql' type as specified in the application
>   configuration.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by adding Entityframework, Npgsql and Npgsql.Entityframework as three individual installs using Nuget. Then the following config...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="[Name of EF Context class]" connectionString="Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=[Name of existing database];User Id=[username];Password=[password];" providerName="Npgsql" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, Npgsql.EntityFramework"></provider>
    </providers>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionFactory, Npgsql.EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Npgsql" />
      <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" support="FF" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for Postgresql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a DbProvidersFactories instead of the connection string:

```
<system.data>
<DbProviderFactories>
  <remove invariant="Npgsql" />
  <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" support="FF" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for Postgresql"  type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" />
</DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Comment: I put it after the <entityFramework> section and same result as before.

Comment: Actually it should be in <system.data>. See here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/783552/Using-PostgreSQL-with-Entity-Framework-in-ASP-NET

Comment: Yes I meant I put the whole thing.

Comment: Looks like there is pre-release NUGET package that could be of help? https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql.EF6/2.0.12-pre4

Comment: Do you have other projects in the solution that might have EF (or SQL) references? Could try adding nuget references for EF there or just clean and reinstall EF if all else fails.

Comment: Yes I do but I was getting errors previously with this specific app.config so I figured that was the one it was using. There's no other config file with a reference to the Sql Server provider.

Comment: Npgsql.EF6/2.0.12-pre4 is a very old package.